# CSS Expand parent div to fit child div width when zoom in

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with no width specified(it has a default width of 1440 px). There is a child div inside it of which width is 980px and centered. When i zoom in to the divs, parent div width shrink according to the zooming. It get smaller than its child div and child div overflows. But i want parent div not to shorten then child div. It's minimum width must be at least 980px. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent it from shrinking you can use **min-width:980px** in parent div.

But ideally if it has been coded right the ratio of the div's should be in sync in zooming.

Hope that helps.

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: what do you mean by saying codded right? i did not code something a lot. i just gave a height of 85px, zero margin, some color to parent div. And child div has a width of 980 px and margin-right and left is auto.